# Show/Hide Text with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to display full text on a page, but only display the first paragraph and use a Read More button to then display hidden text. I'd like to just be able to do this with CSS and no jQuery but can't think of the best way to do it. Any ideas?

So something along the lines of:

```
<p class="lead">This is the intro text</p>
<p>Read more</p>
<p class="hide"> This is the rest of the text, which is hidden on page load</p>
```

Then CSS would do the rest, but I can't think what to do!

Comment: Click functions generally require JS barring a checkbox hack which I generally wouldn't recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'reversible' click type function here is the checkbox alternative.

[**CodePen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eoiAt)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p class="lead">This is the intro text</p>
  <label for="toggle-1">Read More</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-1">
  <p class="hide"> This is the rest of the text, which is hidden on page load</p>
</div>
```

**CSS** (with some basic styling)

```
div {
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid lightgrey;
  padding:10px;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}

label {
  background:lightblue;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow:2px 3px 4px grey;
  border:1px solid blue;
}

label:active {
  box-shadow:0px 1px 2px grey;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  /* For mobile, it's typically better to position checkbox on top of clickable
  area and turn opacity to 0 instead. */
}

/* Toggled State */
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .hide {
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out :

http://www.fiveforblogger.com/2011/10/pure-css-read-more-arrow-button.html

```
<b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
  <div class='jump-link'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url + "#more"'><data:post.jumpText/></a>  
  </div>
</b:if>

CHANGE TO THIS
<a expr:href='data:post.url + "#more"'>Read more</a>


.jump-link {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.jump-link a {
  float: left;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 0 14px;
  background: #0ac92b;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none; 
} 

.jump-link a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -12px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0ac92b;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 12px 0 12px 12px;  
}

.jump-link a:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.jump-link a:hover:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pseudo class selector `:target`.

Tweaking a bit your HTML code:

```
<p class="lead">This is the intro text</p>
<a href="#full">Read more</a>
<p id="full" class="hide"> This is the rest of the text, which is hidden on page load</p>
```

And using simple CSS:

```
.hide { display: none;}
p:target {display:block;}
```

You can check it live in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/mzMKg/).

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<article class="foo">
    <p>This is the first para</p>
    <p>More paras</p>
    <p>More paras</p>
    <p>More paras</p>
</article>
```

JS:

```
$('article.foo').children('p').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);

    if ($this.is(':first-child')) {
        $this.after('<p class="more">Read more...</p>');
    } else {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});

$('article.foo').on('click', 'p.more', function() {
    $(this).parent('article.foo').children('p').each(function() {            
        $(this).show();
    });
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrispickford/5ETZY/1/

Comment: He said "I'd like to just be able to do this with CSS and no jQuery".